# Ajax Double Call

Tags: ajax, double, call

with this function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxcall(div, page)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
else
  { xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",page,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

i use my ajax. But in the page i call 2 times this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">ajaxcall("menu", "perfil.php");</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">ajaxcall('mapadiv', "map2.php");</script>
```

But happens that only one of them works, if i remove one the other works. What im doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It might be possible that second call to ajaxcall() overwrites first call. Try to bind ajaxcall() to click of a button. This URL might help https://blueprints.dev.java.net/ajax-faq.html#concurrent_requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try declaring "var xmlhttp" when the function execution begins.

Comment: thankyou, your method worked. Im a begginer in ajax so im not so good at it. thank you ashwini, michael and shahid!

Comment: wierd isn't it. It would be great if you could learn more about closures in javascript. Dat was the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that ajaxcall is throwing an error and causing the execution to stop.

Run it through a debugger and find out whats going wrong (Firebird, Chrome Developer Tools etc).

Answer (score 0):

first time when you call the function ajaxcall the xmlhttp object is created and by the time you send the request, you are calling the same function and the object is over written. That's the reason only one request is working.inorder to avoid this you may want to store the objects in an array and then process it.